# Getting Error retrieving field value from bean Exception with JasperReports API

Tags: java, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I am trying to get a sample report generated by *JasperReports* but it is throwing some exception that I can not understand.

I have a bean:

```
class DataBean {

    public String country;
    public String name;

    public String getCountry() {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

A class that results list of above bean:

```
class DataBeanList {
    public ArrayList<DataBean> getDataBeanList() {
        ArrayList<DataBean> dataBeanList = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
        dataBeanList.add(produce("Manisha", "India"));
        dataBeanList.add(produce("Dennis Ritchie", "USA"));
        dataBeanList.add(produce("V.Anand", "India"));
        dataBeanList.add(produce("Shrinath", "California"));
        return dataBeanList;
    }

    private DataBean produce(String name, String country) {
        DataBean dataBean = new DataBean();
        dataBean.setName(name);
        dataBean.setCountry(country);
        return dataBean;
    }
}
```

This is how i am doing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String sourceFileName = "/home/oodles/Samples/jasper_report_template.jasper";
    DataBeanList DataBeanList = new DataBeanList();
    ArrayList<DataBean> dataList = DataBeanList.getDataBeanList();
    System.out.println("<<<" + dataList.get(0).getCountry());
    JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
    JRBeanCollectionDataSource beanColDataSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(dataList, false);
    report.setDataSource(beanColDataSource);
    Map parameters = new HashMap();
    try {
        JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(sourceFileName, parameters,
                beanColDataSource);
    } catch (JRException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The Exception is the following:

```
    net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : country
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1331)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1232)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1208)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1554)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:909)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:841)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:88)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:542)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillToFile(JasperFillManager.java:494)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReportToFile(JasperFillManager.java:874)
    at com.general.ReportsMain.main(ReportsMain.java:80)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Property 'country' has no getter method in class 'class com.general.DataBean'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1318)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:762)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:837)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
    ... 15 more
```

In case you need to see .jasper file source:

 i am attaching only fields to show only meaningful code here:

```
<field name="country" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[country]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
<field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Unable to retrieve value from a JavaBean while generating reports using JasperReports API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18119754/876298)

Comment: @AlexK thanks buddy for pointing me to right solution

Comment: I accept this question is a duplicate question as i thought it could not have been asked before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Finally i figured out what you need to do to avoid any exception:

Your datasource is accessed in other packages to extract data from them and if the bean of your datasource is not public then it's not possible to access the class.

SO you need to make your class public (the bean class).

Comment: then there must be some other problem and that does not mean this answer does not work.