# Sum value of List into Bean with iReport

Tags: java, jpa, jasper-reports, ireport

Well, i have the following relationship:

```
  One Dentist have one or many Historys.
```

See a peace of my Class in JPA:

```
 public class Dentista extends AbstractBean {

           @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "dentista", targetEntity = HistoricoCaixaDentista.class)
        private List<HistoricoCaixaDentista> historicosCaixa;
```

I created a JRBeanCollectionDataSource passing a list of "Dentista" with EAGER "historicosCaixa" inside each bean.

In *iReport* I created the following field: `$F{historicosCaixa.valor}`, but when I try to execute the report I got the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'valor' on class 'class org.hibernate.collection.PersistentBag'
```

I tried the following too: In *iReport* click in 'Edit Query', open 'JavaBean DataSource', type my class ('br.com.odontonew.bean.Dentista'), click 'Read Attrbutes'.

After i click twice in 'historicosCaixa' property but just show 'empty' word.

**EDIT 1**

This is my HistoricoCaixaDentista class and your supperclass.

```
public class HistoricoCaixaDentista extends HistoricoCaixa {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static final String FIND_BY_DENTISTA = "HistoricoCaixaDentista.findByDentista";

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_dentista")
    private Dentista dentista;


        public Dentista getDentista() {
            return dentista;
        }


        public void setDentista(Dentista dentista) {
            this.dentista = dentista;
        }


}

public class HistoricoCaixa extends AbstractBean {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Column
    private String descricao;

    @Column
    private double valor;

    @Column(name = "data_hora")
    @Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date dataHora;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_usuario")
    private Usuario usuario;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_forma_pagamento")
    private FormaPagamento formaPagamento;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_historico_pagamento")
    private HistoricoPagamento historicoPagamento;

    public String getDescricao() {
    return descricao;
    }

    public void setDescricao(String descricao) {
    this.descricao = descricao;
    }

    public double getValor() {
    return valor;
    }

    public void setValor(double valor) {
    this.valor = valor;
    }

    public Date getDataHora() {
    return dataHora;
    }

    public void setDataHora(Date dataHora) {
    this.dataHora = dataHora;
    }

    public Usuario getUsuario() {
    return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(Usuario usuario) {
    this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public FormaPagamento getFormaPagamento() {
    return formaPagamento;
    }

    public void setFormaPagamento(FormaPagamento formaPagamento) {
    this.formaPagamento = formaPagamento;
    }

    public HistoricoPagamento getHistoricoPagamento() {
    return historicoPagamento;
    }

    public void setHistoricoPagamento(HistoricoPagamento historicoPagamento) {
    this.historicoPagamento = historicoPagamento;
    }

    public String getColorStyle() {
    if (this.valor > 0) {
        return "background-color:blue";
    } else {
        return "background-color:red";
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to retrieve value from a JavaBean while generating reports using JasperReports API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119754/unable-to-retrieve-value-from-a-javabean-while-generating-reports-using-jasperre)

Comment: i already read this post, and my class 'HistoricoCaixaDentista' is public.

Comment: And what about the field *valor*?

Comment: my 'HistoricoCaixaDentista' is extended from 'HistoricoCaixa'. i edited my post with this two classes.