# JRException: Error retrieving field value: pkgdatelist

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I am new to jasper reports. I am trying to generate an invoice bill using List.

I referred [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12209300/jrbeancollectiondatasource-how-to-show-data-from-the-java-util-list-from-javabe) post for a little help but I am getting this JRException

My jasper Filling Code

```
        String [] prod = request.getParameterValues("prodn[]");
        String [] pkgdate = request.getParameterValues("pkgdate[]");
        String [] manufact = request.getParameterValues("manufact[]");
        String [] exp = request.getParameterValues("exp[]");
        String [] batch = request.getParameterValues("batch[]");
        String [] unit = request.getParameterValues("unit[]");
        String [] qty = request.getParameterValues("qty[]");
        String [] subtot = request.getParameterValues("subtot[]");
Map<String, Object> param = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, param, getDataSource(prod,pkgdate,manufact,exp,batch,unit,qty,subtot));
        JasperViewer.viewReport(jasperPrint, false);
            } 
        catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
    }

    private static JRDataSource getDataSource(String[] prod, String[] pkgdate,
            String[] manufact, String[] exp, String[] batch, String[] unit,
            String[] qty, String[] subtot) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Collection<DataBean> coll = new ArrayList<DataBean>();
        DataBean bean = null;
        for(int i=0;i<prod.length;i++)
        {
            bean = new DataBean(Arrays.asList(prod[i]),Arrays.asList(pkgdate[i]),Arrays.asList(manufact[i]),Arrays.asList(exp[i]),Arrays.asList(batch[i]),Arrays.asList(unit[i]),Arrays.asList(qty[i]),Arrays.asList(subtot[i]));
            coll.add(bean);
        }
        return new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(coll);
    }
```

My bean

```
private List<String> p_names;
    private List<String> p_pkg;
    private List<String> p_manf;
    private List<String> p_exp;
    private List<String> p_batch;
    private List<String> p_unit;
    private List<String> p_qty;
    private List<String> p_sub;

    public DataBean(List<String> prodnamelist,List<String> pkgdatelist,List<String> manfdatelist,List<String> expdatelist,List<String> batchlist,List<String> unitlist,List<String> qtylist,List<String> subtotlist) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
         p_names = prodnamelist;
           p_pkg = pkgdatelist;
           p_manf = manfdatelist;
           p_exp = expdatelist;
           p_batch = batchlist;
           p_unit = unitlist;
           p_qty = qtylist;
           p_sub = subtotlist;
    }

    public List<String> getP_names() {
        return p_names;
    }

    public List<String> getP_pkg() {
        return p_pkg;
    }

    public List<String> getP_manf() {
        return p_manf;
    }

    public List<String> getP_exp() {
        return p_exp;
    }

    public List<String> getP_batch() {
        return p_batch;
    }

    public List<String> getP_unit() {
        return p_unit;
    }

    public List<String> getP_qty() {
        return p_qty;
    }


    public List<String> getP_sub() {
        return p_sub;
    }
```

My jrxml file

As the jrxml file is very long I am posting only that which is required

```
<subDataset name="tableDataset" uuid="f13e6d36-5148-4ecc-bbe3-3035def80980">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="prodname" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="pkgdate" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="manfdate" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="expdate" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="batch" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="unit" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="qty" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
        <field name="subtot" class="java.lang.String">
            <fieldDescription><![CDATA[_THIS]]></fieldDescription>
        </field>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="pkgdatelist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="manfdatelist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="expdatelist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="batchlist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="unitlist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="qtylist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="subtotlist" class="java.util.Collection"/>
    <field name="prodnamelist" class="java.util.Collection"/>

<componentElement>
                <reportElement x="0" y="90" width="79" height="30" uuid="48bd4b3d-a43c-4e57-89ad-d1114b214e29"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="012ce25a-4b36-4400-97e2-a0ec1e27bb80">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{prodnamelist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="79">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="79" height="30" uuid="8cf1ecb5-5fdf-4dc9-a970-244f4d31a1b9"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{prodname}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="79" y="90" width="71" height="30" uuid="48bd4b3d-a43c-4e57-89ad-d1114b214e29"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="012ce25a-4b36-4400-97e2-a0ec1e27bb80">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{pkgdatelist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="71">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="71" height="30" uuid="5d91cd84-0beb-40e7-94bc-0ee2e846755f"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{pkgdate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="150" y="90" width="70" height="30" uuid="c002cbfb-ca6e-4939-91c8-30a8dccbc650"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="c4885197-91d5-4e41-935f-fbbae897321f">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{manfdatelist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="70">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="ff5f611b-f905-49f6-92bf-70ef1df02d5f"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{manfdate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="220" y="90" width="70" height="30" uuid="991c37d9-4c9c-4340-ab5f-810903caa8b6"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="2b5275d1-ae2f-4cfd-8c32-79f64c304af9">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{expdatelist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="70">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="70" height="30" uuid="93eb71d7-a7a6-442e-a2cc-3506b3854ccb"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{expdate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="290" y="90" width="74" height="30" uuid="0472dba7-8574-4bd2-bd6f-7c7329862a85"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="ce839cd3-8fe2-4987-8db1-b24876e254cb">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{batchlist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="74">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="74" height="30" uuid="5e64886e-e3c4-4dfb-94c0-25abf57b6c76"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{batch}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="364" y="90" width="66" height="30" uuid="ea485a88-82fb-4c35-a5f4-ac5aeee9fdff"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="80698e51-9a06-446a-9f20-a07e315a4ec1">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{unitlist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="66">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="66" height="30" uuid="07f81482-f9a1-4d8b-aea4-2e72dd0c05b8"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{unit}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="429" y="90" width="51" height="30" uuid="9c591eea-e3e7-4139-aca1-971ab385cc81"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="9ee1f855-3abc-4818-ab16-f1a175de9c01">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{qtylist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="51">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="51" height="30" uuid="57c13e54-42c3-400d-93b0-f14f60b41751"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{qty}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement x="480" y="90" width="76" height="30" uuid="1965ad12-e2d4-4b8c-a2a1-e6f981bd2238"/>
                <jr:list xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd" printOrder="Vertical">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="tableDataset" uuid="92d5aeb4-83a9-4ca1-937f-04d93f796bb8">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{subtotlist})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:listContents height="30" width="76">
                        <textField>
                            <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="71" height="30" uuid="d32c54e2-a4a8-4027-a5ed-1399a1b39d85"/>
                            <textElement textAlignment="Center"/>
                            <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{subtot}]]></textFieldExpression>
                        </textField>
                    </jr:listContents>
                </jr:list>
            </componentElement>
```

The error is at the field `pkgdatelist`

Error

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : pkgdatelist
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:123)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:96)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:100)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1358)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1259)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1235)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1588)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:149)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:939)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:871)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:114)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:653)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:969)
    at com.medicam.servlets.GenerateReportForPurchase.doPost(GenerateReportForPurchase.java:110)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:526)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:655)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1566)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1523)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'pkgdatelist' on class 'class com.medicam.servlets.DataBean'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1313)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:762)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:837)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:426)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:111)
    ... 37 more
```

Comment: May be this help you: [Unable to retrieve value from a JavaBean while generating reports using JasperReports API](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18119754/876298)

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the names of the fields as the ones declared in the bean.
So, instead of `<field name="pkgdatelist"...` use `<field name="p_pkg"...` etc.