# net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

Below is my jrxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="blank" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="8f53d82e-ed85-4565-8399-a927ab4886f2">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <parameter name="sdate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="edate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="checkupLogoPath" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="arrow" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="buildingName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="establishedDate" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="ctor" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="grossFloorArea" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="purpose" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="inUseAccountNumber" class="java.lang.Integer"/>
    <field name="regionName" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="detailContent" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemImage1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemImage2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemEmployeeInfo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="orderContent" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemVoiceRecord" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemCreateDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemReason" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="resultImage1" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="resultImage2" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="solutionMethod" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="resultEmployeeInfo" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="resultVoiceRecord" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="resultCreateDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="problemType" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="70" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="190" y="20" width="180" height="30" uuid="901c32e5-478c-4142-bc68-0db60c972575">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="SansSerif" size="24" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[문 제 보 고 서]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="400" y="20" width="100" height="15" uuid="e0c8b6d1-9441-4f66-8033-d61c37b7dce0">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{sdate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="400" y="35" width="100" height="15" uuid="0e0f3d56-7440-4292-8212-73327e831773">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{edate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="50" y="25" width="91" height="19" uuid="2b486c1d-653d-42da-82dc-ccfd8917a372">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{checkupLogoPath}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="677" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="40" y="10" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="e62fdf04-3f64-4dfc-b3af-d8cb647245cc">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{buildingName}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="255" y="35" width="249" height="20" uuid="96f85dc0-deb7-4db2-8243-e27df6e94104"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{address}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="230" y="35" width="25" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="5ceb45bc-8f6c-4b6f-868d-b4e6b27a1b74">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[주소]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="305" y="10" width="81" height="20" forecolor="#555555" uuid="fc7abbfd-d4cd-45f0-a9c2-8431c1621796"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{establishedDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="270" y="10" width="35" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="c7fe33c0-698d-43a0-942e-063951cecbcd"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[완공일]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="421" y="10" width="82" height="20" uuid="b830640a-cd40-4b74-b21a-7923897f192b"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{ctor}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="386" y="10" width="35" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="f59cfc82-2e74-4ed2-8e01-b0d195a5dbb1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[시공사]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="180" y="10" width="85" height="20" uuid="d4472a09-1da4-4480-8ad0-8ae96824ce42"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{grossFloorArea}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="145" y="10" width="35" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="4946cc21-ded7-43cc-a975-ad8ff919ec8b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[연면적]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="40" y="35" width="100" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="4ee192fd-fc5a-4b37-a10c-bf752781592e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="10"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{purpose}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="180" y="35" width="30" height="20" uuid="3e95f030-20da-4995-8db7-3cdba0b2ce31"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{inUseAccountNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="145" y="35" width="35" height="20" forecolor="#333333" uuid="31c1013f-9e28-4e86-87e8-58453476690b">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[직원수]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="40" y="65" width="475" height="1" forecolor="#333333" backcolor="#333333" uuid="1ae177bb-ba9e-4b53-bea4-a88d1b3681f9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineStyle="Solid"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <frame>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Opaque" x="40" y="80" width="475" height="24" forecolor="#B5B5B5" backcolor="#B5B5B5" uuid="ba6fd0b9-8590-439f-aaaf-05c5d5ad83a5">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="270" y="0" width="50" height="24" uuid="4216437b-6a69-420e-af2b-c57c3603aced">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[[처리후]]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="320" y="0" width="150" height="24" uuid="07c50f06-1cf7-4622-a6ef-7b5a7b0e6d17">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{resultCreateDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="80" y="0" width="150" height="24" forecolor="#666666" uuid="86983134-0214-4a3e-8242-245aca8bab21">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemCreateDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="30" y="0" width="50" height="24" forecolor="#666666" uuid="f606e2fc-8f88-41aa-b9ac-01b0bd032c4e">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[[처리전]]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <image>
                    <reportElement x="231" y="0" width="12" height="24" uuid="0cd82bcf-1fbb-479c-a3d0-c679441c2f2d">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <imageExpression><![CDATA[$P{arrow}]]></imageExpression>
                </image>
            </frame>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="40" y="130" width="475" height="1" uuid="0bcadc24-2a06-4cff-8f92-cdeaf8c0cc97">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="2.0"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="40" y="150" width="100" height="15" forecolor="#666666" uuid="c9ead5e1-13f1-4cf5-956f-69662415f98a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{detailContent}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" mode="Transparent" x="40" y="135" width="45" height="15" forecolor="#666666" uuid="02033a4b-0efc-4e69-baa9-ebdd307c9e51">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[세부사항]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="150" width="100" height="15" uuid="ac5d455b-c377-45e2-911a-f637df6b46e9">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{orderContent}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="135" width="45" height="15" uuid="02a1fed2-7d73-4d9c-ba4a-051d588c6db3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[지시사항]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="160" y="135" width="110" height="15" forecolor="#666666" uuid="227e9d31-9ab4-40bb-86fd-8acd9e0bcaca">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemEmployeeInfo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="415" y="135" width="100" height="15" uuid="74727c83-f58c-4b0f-b130-867f8e767aca"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{resultEmployeeInfo}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="240" width="100" height="15" uuid="70637064-d2e2-463f-8660-f1775732a11c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{solutionMethod}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="225" width="80" height="15" uuid="2d70c904-051a-49ab-8eb4-6b7c36d73b4d">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[해결방안 및 결과]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="195" width="100" height="15" uuid="25e245dd-4003-448b-b004-fe6a6fa224c1">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemReason}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="180" width="45" height="15" uuid="499a134d-b2ab-4a2e-8c9c-6af5e8280e76">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[문제원인]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="277" y="130" width="1" height="544" forecolor="#333333" uuid="d69a1e7c-afc8-4fad-b4ca-da06a5e76c12">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="40" y="674" width="475" height="1" uuid="516bf661-bed7-48ab-8567-1fefe4e16338">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="40" y="300" width="45" height="15" forecolor="#666666" uuid="949230d0-8d8c-44cd-893d-d417d509d984">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[첨부사진]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="280" y="300" width="45" height="15" forecolor="#666666" uuid="ac6500df-5c65-43a5-922f-5198bf6df65c">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="11"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[첨부사진]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="40" y="320" width="232" height="158" uuid="9c235101-bee0-46ca-a04e-fe4feb0bbba6">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemImage1}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="40" y="485" width="232" height="158" uuid="b4dfcae1-3566-4940-8bc9-8c55b2763d8a">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemImage2}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" mode="Transparent" x="280" y="320" width="232" height="158" uuid="8c8d1d29-8909-43c9-bd62-683a84c6de88">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{resultImage1}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="485" width="232" height="158" uuid="01aeaeca-93db-4d61-bde5-cb1e14635941">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA[$F{resultImage2}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="40" y="650" width="150" height="15" uuid="ca413aa9-8cdf-4cb7-861e-7e779f8e624e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemVoiceRecord}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="280" y="650" width="150" height="15" uuid="5516438b-df5f-4a04-a480-00fd350dc68e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{resultVoiceRecord}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="210" y="35" width="10" height="20" uuid="99307634-05d6-49c3-92cf-e1bdec03b5c8"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <text><![CDATA[명]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <frame>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="40" y="104" width="475" height="24" forecolor="#DFDFDF" backcolor="#DFDFDF" uuid="3d23a4df-87ca-4a9a-90f1-b2e5e4d2fb3e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement key="" mode="Transparent" x="45" y="0" width="370" height="24" forecolor="#333333" uuid="8edd3277-c027-4325-b22c-7ed5d0b26eb3">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{regionName}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
                <staticText>
                    <reportElement x="415" y="0" width="30" height="24" forecolor="#333333" uuid="2f2589ab-85fa-4070-a96d-5131dd9fdcf7">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <text><![CDATA[분류 :]]></text>
                </staticText>
                <textField>
                    <reportElement x="445" y="0" width="30" height="24" forecolor="#333333" uuid="abbf3461-38d4-497d-80a1-33fb67cb3427">
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.height" value="pixel"/>
                        <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    </reportElement>
                    <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                        <font size="12"/>
                    </textElement>
                    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{problemType}]]></textFieldExpression>
                </textField>
            </frame>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="40" y="0" width="475" height="1" forecolor="#333333" backcolor="#333333" uuid="a09f1941-9223-48ba-9b0d-4268d9473546">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.y" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.width" value="pixel"/>
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
            </line>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="34" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="177" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="4f5e482f-2e45-4e3d-ad85-ea33d28a4c2e">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Page " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement mode="Transparent" x="277" y="0" width="100" height="30" uuid="583dd649-a17e-4abc-89d1-d81c222918d3">
                    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.unit.x" value="pixel"/>
                </reportElement>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left" verticalAlignment="Middle"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" of " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

When I run this, I get an error meassge like :

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean : regionName
```

How can I fix this??? I already wasting a lot of my time to fix this. I use Intellij. When I made getter and setter method, I use autoComplete. I dont know why this error can happen.

I saw on SO several similar questions, but nothing is working for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to retrieve value from a JavaBean while generating reports using JasperReports API](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18119754/unable-to-retrieve-value-from-a-javabean-while-generating-reports-using-jasperre)

Comment: You need to show your bean containing the public String getRegioneName()